# SOAP API pass through in WSO2 API manager v3.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using the latest version of WSO2 API manager and am trying to consume a SOAP API backend as pass-through. I am not able to invoke the API because in the latest version there is no option to paste the soap request and soap action. The documentation states that it is there but when I stood it up as a docker container, the ability to pass in the soap request is not there. Can anyone confirm if it is a bug and whether I should downgrade to the previous version?
https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/Learn/Tutorials/expose-a-soap-service-as-a-rest-api/

[WSO2 documentation screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7mBU.png)

[WSO2 Dev portal SOAP API pass through invocation screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Teyil.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the SOAP Action and SOAP Request parameters to the Swagger definition.

1. Login to API Publisher and open the api.
2. Goto API Definition tab from the left menu.
3. Click on Edit button.
4. In the swagger editor, add the following definition under the POST method parameters and save the api.

```
      - schema:
        type: string
        description: SOAP request.
        name: SOAP Request
        required: true
        in: body
      - description: SOAPAction header for soap 1.1
        name: SOAPAction
        type: string
        required: false
        in: header
```

Created an issue for this, since this needs to be fixed in the new version.
https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/6813

Comment: Thanks. I was able to use the suggested workaround.

Comment: Here is the exact swagger definition piece I had to add.
       `parameters: 
          - name: "SOAP Request"
            in: "body"
            description: "SOAP request"
            required: true
            schema:
              type: "string"
          - name: "SOAPAction"
            in: "header"
            description: "SOAPAction header"
            required: false
            type: "string"`